# find group of rows in a matrix with pattern similar to another matrix

Tags: r, clustering, pattern-recognition

I've been scratching my head about this problem for some time:

I have a big gene expression dataset (20k genes x 200 samples) in matrix A and i have a subset of this dataset (i.e. 40 genes x 200 samples) copied in matrix B. I would like to find groups of genes in matrix A that resemble as close as possible the patterns in matrix B.

I am looking into various clustering methods including KNN and SOTA where for example I would be training KNN with matrix B and cluster matrix A...but I'm not sure this is actually giving me the answer I want.

any suggestions?

Comment: Define "patterns".

Comment: pattern as:  gene expression values across multiple samples...but for multiple genes

Comment: Define "resemble as close as possible". :)

Comment: @Alexis, very good point :)...basically the whole point is that I want to use my gene signature as a "bait" and, parsing the whole dataset, find clusters that correlate with my gene signature..i found lots of tools that identify gene signatures from scratch, but i'm having a hard time (or i'm searching in the wrong way) finding R functions/tools that do it by similarity with a predefined signature...hope this makes sense

Comment: How do you intend to measure whether it correlates? What is a candidate for matching? Is there any way to speed it up beyond testing all candidates?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ...that's what I'm trying to find out :) I could create all the possible combinations, calculate correlation/linear model and extract those that match but it'll take ages since my signature is made not by one single gene but by numerous genes

Comment: Well, unless you can put your "pattern" into some mathematical form, it will be hard to suggest you anything. Have you looked at how patterns in coclustering are defined?

Comment: I looked up some biclustering algorithm but not sure that's what you mean..do you have any references that I could look up?